# Check running status of an application on a remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, remote-access, system.diagnostics

I wish to track the running status of certain applications on a remote machine, none of them system applications like `system` or `idle` etc.

I am using `System.Diagnostics.Process` class and the `GetProcessesByName(string processname, string systemID)` for this purpose.

When i try and do this for a remote machine, I get an error saying 'Access Denied'.

Researching around, it seems several reasons, such as the user under whom the application / service is running.

I have tried elevating the user, under whose account my service (the tracking application) will be running, but it did not seem to have worked.

What are the user privileges required for this to work? And where should they be applied? If the same user is not available on the remote machine, will this work?

Answer (score 0):

To have remote access to a computer, you should have permissions / rights on the `target` computer, otherwise this would be a HUGE security leak.

So either add your account there, or use the credentials of a user that exists on the target computer.

After some digging:

> If the current user does not have proper access to the remote computer, the call to *RegConnectRegistry* fails. To connect to a remote registry, call **LogonUser** with LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS and **ImpersonateLoggedOnUser** before calling RegConnectRegistry.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724840(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `use the credentials of a user that exists on the target computer`  - How would I accomplish that? And which permissions / rights would I be looking for?

Comment: Updated with some more info found when digging trough `System.dll`